# Pull To Refresh crashes app if I try to scroll while refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented Pull to Refresh on my app but it crashes when I try to scroll while it is still refreshing. here is the code I'm using:
FYI, I'm calling webServices while refreshing.

In ViewDidLoad:

```
UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(callWebService:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;
    [self callWebService:refresh];
```

Method for refresh:

```
-(void)callWebService:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh
{
    static BOOL refreshInProgress = NO;
    MessageWebServices *messageWebService = [[MessageWebServices alloc]init];

    MessageBO *tempBO = [[MessageBO alloc]init];

    if(self.flag)
    {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"My Posts";
        tempBO.projectId = [AppConstants getProjectId];
        tempBO.customerId =[AppConstants getCustomerId];

    }
    else
    {
        tempBO.projectId = [AppConstants getProjectId];
    }


    self.messageStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (!refreshInProgress)
    {
        refreshInProgress = YES;

        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            self.messageStore = [messageWebService getMessageList:tempBO];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [refresh beginRefreshing];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [refresh endRefreshing];
                refreshInProgress = NO;
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: your coding is fine check once self.messageStore values are added or not

Comment: Thanks, man. I realized I was initializing the array again. I removed that line and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `beginRefreshing` method. You can easily add refresh control to your tableView.

```
#pragma mark Refresh Method

-(void)startRefreshing {
    if (!self.refreshControl) {
        // Initialize the refresh control.
        self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = CRREFRESHBGCOLOR;
        self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(callWebservice) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [yourTable addSubview:self.refreshControl];//add refresh control to your table
    }
}

-(void)endRefreshing {
    if (self.refreshControl) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last update: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                    forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
        NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrsDictionary];
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle;

        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

After calling/finishing web-service method call `[self endRefreshing];` method and reload your table `[yourTable reloadData]`.